# � characters importing CSV file

Tags: php, character-encoding

UPDATE: After checking if Ajax was sending the CSV data with the correct characters, I confirm you it does, it is on the PHP side where those get wrong:

[image: img]

---

I am importing a CSV file with spanish characters (á, ñ, ó, etc...). After importing, words like "Germán" transform to "Germ�n".

This is the code:

```
$csv=$_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name'];
          $csv= mb_convert_encoding($csv, "UTF-8");
            $handle = fopen($csv, "r"); 
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) { 
                   ............
```

Some of my tries with no possitive result have been:

```
$csv=$_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name'];
$csv= mb_convert_encoding($csv, "UTF-8");
```

and

```
$precsv=$_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name'];
$csv=utf8_encode($precsv);
```

as well as setting on top of this PHP file this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

None of this makes characters importcorrectly, and so neither being properly inserted on Database, that is UTF8_general_ci encoded and just omits the rest of any value from the � till its end

Comment: Why are you converting the encoding of the *file name* instead of the contents of the file?

Comment: huh... ok give me a minute

Comment: what encoding was this csv file in to begin with? no much point in re-encoding to utf8 if it's already utf8...

Comment: I work with tmp_name because it is not uploaded itself in any place, I store  $_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name'], extract each row and insert it.

Comment: Those have been the tries I had made in order to solve the problem. If the problem is not related to UTF-8 enconding as it already has that encode, could you tell me the reason for the wrong characters?

Comment: Update added with some more info on top of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely to do with encoding and you are on the right track, with one mistep; the first parameter to `mb_convert_encoding` should be the actual string that is to be converted. Not the filename like you are doing.

So this:

```
$csv=$_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name'];
$csv= mb_convert_encoding($csv, "UTF-8");
```

Should be:

```
$csvContents=file_get_contents($_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name']);
$csvConverted = mb_convert_encoding($csvContents, "UTF-8");
file_put_contents('SomeotherFile.csv', $csvConverted);
```

Obviously this needs some specific tweaks for your situation, but just making sure you are doing the conversion on the actual file contents should be a big step in the right direction.